# Making a graph of function

Tags: functions

I recently started studying Mathematica, so if this is some basic question, sorry about that.

I need to know how to draw a graph of function (2D) where I should sketch on the graph:

- break points (and calculate left and right limits in them)
- asymptotes
- zeros
- extremas

If you have any suggestion of a matereial where I could find explanation for this, please feel free to share that with me. I am clueless and I don't seem to find anything on Google.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Consider the Introductory Video by Socratica: [Plots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSiS_b_h65s).

Comment: It sounds a bit as if you may be looking for root locus plots? If so, RootLocusPlot would likely help.